# Azure - Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, azure

I have opened the visual studio 2010 by right click on it and clicked on "Run as administrator" option. Then I have opened the azure solution project in visual studio. Pressing F5 I got the following message:

> ### Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> There was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process for url "https://127.255.0.0:446/" for role "deployment16(89).projectname.instancename_IN_0_Web"  instance Unable to start debugging on the web server. Visual studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator.

I am a domain user of machine and also I am in local administrator group of the machine. On my machine I have Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. Visual studio 2010 Premium edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of potential reason for this: domain security policy will override the local security policy. I think there are two options for you:

1. Leave the domain when you debug so that local admin can set local policy.
2. Contact your IT to ask the domain admin to change security policy for you.

Comment: I was administrator on the machine. I still added myself in debugging users groups and told domain admin to add myself in security policy for debugging rights. I followed the link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952166/visual-studio-has-insufficient-privileges-to-debug-this-process-to-debug-this-p

But in vain. Then I told domain admin about your comment Arwind and success. I am able to debug. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

If you have VSCommands installed, make sure that `Tools -> VSCommands -> Options -> General ->  Start with Medium Integrity Level` is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be added to the Debugger Users group  by your system administrator.

Edit: Right click on My Computer, manage -> local users and groups -> Groups -> Debugger Users and you should try to add yourself to the group, if you can't ask it to your domain administrator. If you are debugging remotely, you must do the same on target machine.

Comment: I am an administrator on the machine. I specified that I am in a administrators group. Still do I have to be added in debugger group? What is the name of the debugger group? How to add in it?

Comment: I don't have such type of group in my group list. I am debugging locally.